# function which inserts a unique_ptrs into a multimap does not compile ICPC in linux

Tags: c++11, stl, move, unique-ptr, multimap

i am trying to build a multimap with unique_ptr and i am getting strange compilation errors in Linux

Example Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Event {
public:
    Event (double time) : _time(time) {}
    double getTime () const { return _time; }
private:
    Event (Event const & e);
    void operator= (Event const &e);
    double _time;
};

class Calendar {
public:
    void addEvent (std::unique_ptr<Event> e) {
        double t = e->getTime(); // get time before trying the next line
        _events.insert(move(make_pair (t, move(e)))); // insert into multimap
    }
private:
    multimap <double, unique_ptr<Event>> _events;
};

int main () {
    unique_ptr<Event> e (new Event(1.0));

    Calendar c;
    c.addEvent (move(e));
}
```

above code compiles in OSX 10.10 with icpc 15.0.2 20150121 but not CentOS6.6 with the same compiler.  there are a bunch of compiler errors which boil down to this:

> std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type &) [with _Key=double, _Tp=std::unique_ptr>, _Compare=std::less, _Alloc=std::allocator>>>]" at line 21 of "main.cpp"

clearly something is trying to copy the unique_ptr and this is triggering the error.  i have tried this all kinds of different ways and still can't get it to compile in linux.  suggestions?  i would think icpc would support unique_ptr with multimap right?

things i've tried:

1. creating the pair first (works) and then inserting the pair (fails)
2. using/not using make_pair
3. using/not using move

suggestions? i've searched extensively on here before posting and tried most everything

Comment: Works for me. Perhaps compiler/library implementation bug. You can check if `_events.emplace(t, move(e));` works.

Comment: what version of linux/intel compiler where you using?  it works fine for me on OSX & Windows using Intel 15.0.2 and clang to boot.  i will try the emplace

Comment: Looks like an Intel stdlib implementation bug. Your example [compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b158debc8a4c90c) successfully on both gcc and clang.

Comment: multimap has no member emplace according to icpc in CentOS 6.6.  Works fine in OSX.

Answer (score 0):

i talked to the people at Intel and they essentially said "not supported".  basically, compiling code using icpc still takes advantage of the underlying compiler on the system (in this case GCC 4.4.7).  for some things (nullptr for example) icpc supports it even though the underlying gcc doesn't.  for other items (in my case, imbedding unique_ptrs in multimaps) icpc leverages the underlying gcc headers and it simply isn't going to work.

the solution to this problem is: don't do it

Either upgrade your compiler or avoid the code in the first place.